# Is there a more effective way to write this 4x nest cursor loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

Here's my code.

what it is supposed to do is to look at each record in [parentChildRelationship] and if the record has the column [parent_table_name] defined to check and see if the childtable.childcolumn value for each record is found in the parent table.  if it is do nothing if not mark an error flag and write a error message to the problem record.  **each childColumn can have multiple parents.**

everything works as it should but i have to imagine there's a better way to write this...

```
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @cTableName nvarchar(max)

    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT tableName FROM [phil_ic1].[dbo].[parentChildRelationship] where parent_table_id is not null
    OPEN c1
    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @cTableName

    --set @cTableName='enrollment'
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        begin
            DECLARE @cColumnName nvarchar(max)
            DECLARE c2 CURSOR FOR
                SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM [phil_ic1].[dbo].[parentChildRelationship]
                    where parent_table_id is not null
                    and tableName=@cTableName
                    and not (column_type='String' AND column_length is null)
            PRINT  'cTableName: '+@cTableName
            OPEN c2

            FETCH NEXT FROM c2 into @cColumnName
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                BEGIN
                    PRINT ' cColumnName: '+@cColumnName
                    DECLARE @pTableName nvarchar(max)
                    DECLARE c3 CURSOR FOR
                        SELECT parent_table_name from parentChildRelationship
                            WHERE tableName=@cTableName
                            AND column_name=@cColumnName
                    OPEN c3
                    FETCH NEXT FROM c3 into @pTableName
                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                        BEGIN
                            PRINT '     pTableName:'+@pTableName
                            DECLARE @pColumnName nvarchar(max)
                            DECLARE c4 CURSOR FOR
                            SELECT parent_column_name from parentChildRelationship
                                WHERE tableName=@cTableName
                                AND column_name=@cColumnName
                                AND parent_table_name=@pTableName
                            OPEN c4


                            FETCH NEXT FROM c4 INTO @pColumnName
                            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                                BEGIN
                                    DECLARE @upSQL nvarchar(max)
                                    set @upSQL = 'UPDATE [' +@cTableName+'] SET vError = 1,vMessage=concat(vMessage, ''['+@cTableName+'].['+@cColumnName
                                        +']='','+@cColumnName+','' NOT FOUND IN ['+@pTableName+'].['+@pColumnName
                                        +'];  '') WHERE NOT ['+@cColumnName+'] IN (SELECT ['+@pColumnName+'] FROM ['+@pTableName+'])'
                                    --PRINT @upSQL
                                    exec sp_executesql @upSQL
                                    FETCH NEXT FROM c4 into @pColumnName
                                END
                            CLOSE C4
                            DEALLOCATE c4
                            FETCH NEXT FROM c3 into @pTableName
                        END
                        CLOSE C3
                        DEALLOCATE c3
                    FETCH NEXT FROM c2 into @cColumnName
                END
                PRINT 'LOOP'
                CLOSE C2
                DEALLOCATE c2
            FETCH NEXT FROM c1 into @cTableName
        end
        CLOSE c1
        DEALLOCATE c1
END
```

Comment: There is almost certainly a better approach than nesting cursors 4 deep. However, there isn't anywhere near enough information to rewrite this. And more importantly, that is a lot of effort to rewrite this.

Comment: Maybe a recursive cte?

Comment: @SeanLange i thought of using a CTE i have a complete brain fart when trying to build the update statement...

Comment: here's the most important part of code: set @upSQL = 'UPDATE [' +@cTableName+'] SET vError = 1,vMessage=concat(vMessage, ''['+@cTableName+'].['+@cColumnName
                                        +']='','+@cColumnName+','' NOT FOUND IN ['+@pTableName+'].['+@pColumnName
                                        +'];  '') WHERE NOT ['+@cColumnName+'] IN (SELECT ['+@pColumnName+'] FROM ['+@pTableName+'])'

Comment: What is NOT FOUND IN???

Comment: simply a error message concated to the vMessage column of each table stating the value of the child does not exist in the parent table/column

Comment: the vMessage concat statement ends right before the WHERE NOT statement

Comment: Ahh I see it now. Was really struggling trying to figure out what that was. Any chance you can post the table definition and a few rows of sample data so we can see what it really happening here?

Comment: @sean check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Just do ONLY ONE cursor by following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name, tableName, parent_column_name, parent_table_name 
FROM [phil_ic1].[dbo].[parentChildRelationship] 
where parent_table_id is not null
and not (column_type='String' AND column_length is null)
```

Comment: yes. but i need to perform update statements. this returned table does nothing to help this operation.

Comment: Right. You have only one cursor for that query and use values you get for your update.

Answer (score 0):

here's the output of the following query:

```
SELECT tableName 'Child Table', column_name 'Child Column ',parent_table_name 'Parent Table' ,   parent_column_name 'Parent Column'
FROM [phil_ic1].[dbo].[parentChildRelationship] 
where parent_table_id is not null
and not (column_type='String' AND column_length is null)
order by tableName,column_name 



    [Child Table]   [Child Column]  [Parent Table]  [Parent Column]
    contact state   State   Code
    contact studentNum  student studentNum
    counselor   employNum   employee    employNum
    counselor   studentNum  student studentNum
    course  calendarName    calendar    calendarName
    course  department  department  name
    course  schoolNum   calendar    schoolNum
    course  schoolNum   school  schoolNum
```